# Google home device not recognizing the app name however it is working through simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home, api-ai

We tried to access our application using Google Home Device. So, it did not understand the command. If I try the same through test simulator provided by assistant console, it is working fine.

Also, once our application is triggered through the simulator then it also works on the device.

Can anyone let me know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During development, this sounds completely normal. An Action will be made available on all devices using the same account as the simulator once you first activate it in the simulator.

During Alpha and Beta testing, you need to [follow the instructions](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments#get-feedback) to opt-in to the test version of the action.

Comment: Yeah if you want more predictable behavior, the Alpha/Beta features are the way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call "your version will be in the Deploying state for up to 3 hours before it becomes available to your users." more predictable. {: